# parsing/scanning through a 17gb xml file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the stackoverflow dump file (Posts.xml- 17gb) .It is of the form:

```
<posts>
<row Id="15228715" PostTypeId="1" />
.
<row Id="15228716" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="1600647" LastActivityDate="2013-03-05T16:13:24.897"/>
</posts>
```

I have to 'group' each question with their answers. Basically find a question (posttypeid=1) find its answers using parentId of another row and store it in db .

I tried doing this using querypath (DOM), but it kept exiting(139) . My guess is because of the large size of the file, my PC couldn't handle it, even with huge swap.

I considered xmlreader, but as I see it using xmlreader, the program would be reading through the file a whole lot of times(find question, look for answers, repeat a lot of times) and hence is not viable. Am I wrong ?

Is there any other method/way ?

Help!

It is a one time parsing.

Comment: Use `SimpleXMLIterator` Instead ....

Comment: @Baba Not really. See http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/simplexml/simplexml.c#2249. It'll load the whole file into memory and then iterate over it.

Comment: XMLReader will iterate through each node without loading the whole file into memory, but it will only do so once unless you state otherwise.

Comment: It's funny to have to put 15 of the 16 GB into swap and then read from it. it'll take hours.

Comment: I'd consider to fread through the file, from one tag to the next, manually. I don't see any other way here to not have to swap?

Comment: @bwoebi Wow ... Interesting .... but even `fseek` would not work since its `XML`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I considered xmlreader, but as I see it using xmlreader, the program would be reading through the file a whole lot of times(find question, look for answers, repeat a lot of times) and hence is not viable. Am I wrong ?

Yes you are wrong. With XMLReader you specify your own how often your want to traverse the file (you normally do it *once*). For your case I see no reason why you should not be able to even insert this 1:1 on each `<row>` element. You can decide per the attribute which database (table?) you would like to insert into.

I normally suggest a set of Iterators that make traversing with XMLReader easier. It's called [XMLReaderIterator](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator) and allows to *`foreach`* over the *`XMLReader`* so that the code is often easier to read and write:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xmlFile);

/* @var $users XMLReaderNode[] - iterate over all <post><row> elements */
$posts = new XMLElementIterator($reader, 'row');
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    $isAnswerInsteadOfQuestion = (bool)$post->getAttribute('ParentId')

    $importer = $isAnswerInsteadOfQuestion 
                ? $importerAnswers 
                : $importerQuestions;

    $importer->importRowNode($post);
}
```

If you are concerned about the order (e.g. you might fear that some answers parent's aren't available while the answers are), I would take care inside the importer layer, not inside the traversal.

Depending if that happens often, very often, never or quite never I would use a different strategy. E.g. for *never* I would insert directly into database tables with foreign key constraints activated. If *often*, I would create an insert transaction for the whole import in which the key constraints are lifted and re-activated at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your time, you were right that I was wrong. I was successfully able to use xmlreader to solve my predicament. 2 things I noticed: the answers were always after the question (obviosuly) and the answers were present within the next few thousand rows (few exceptions are ok), so wrote the script to cache a few thousand questions, look for their answers , array_splice half the array and repeat! Thanks again

Comment: "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'XMLElementIterator' not found"

Answer (score 2):

Because the way you are processing this large file isn't sequential but requires direct access, I think the only viable option is to load the data into an XML database.

Comment: agree.  Sometimes I think people overlook the most simple of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP xmlreader seems to be the right thing to do.

Reason:
 Because of your statement:

> I have to 'group' each question with their answers. Basically find a
>   question (posttypeid=1) find its answers using parentId of another row
>   and store it in db.

What I understand is you like to build a database with questions an answers. Therefore, there is no reason to do the "grouping" on the XML level. Put all relevant information in the database and do the grouping on the DB level - with db commands (sql ...).

What you have to is  use something like "Using the target parser method" E.g [High-performance XML parsing in Python with [xml](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-hiperfparse/) (Even if it is for Python, it's a good start). This should be possible with XMLReader.